# WCF service Error for large amount of data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, wcf

I have a WCF service running on my application. Whenever I pass large amount of data to the service I get this error

> The remote server returned an unexpected response: (413) Request Entity Too Large.

How to solve this error?

I did R&D on this issue but did not find any suitable answers.

I am creating an entity dynamically which contains 53 fields, but when I try to add the 54th field this error is thrown.

Comment: try 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20575946/the-remote-server-returned-an-unexpected-response-413-request-entity-too-larg  2.     http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/521725/Request-Entity-Too-Large

Comment: edit wcf configuration ->bind setting-> Max received buffer size and give it max value

Comment: I had this issue early this week and I tried the solutions suggested by @Agalo, they are good but didn't work for me, although they pointed me to the right direction, I realizaed that rather than use <basicHttpBinding> you can use <webHttpBinding> and it works. Also there are a couple of IIS params that can affect but not in my case.

Answer (score 2):

The problem arises due to file size of the image

> Can't upload large files using IIS

The fix is simply to up the size of the `UploadReadAheadSize` metabase property.

Reference [1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jiruss/archive/2007/04/13/http-413-request-entity-too-large-can-t-upload-large-files-using-iis6.aspx),[2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/521725/Request-Entity-Too-Large),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122957/iis7-413-request-entity-too-large-uploadreadaheadsize)

Comment: But no file is being uploaded..Got the solution. Web.config file for web service needs to be modified with receivedbuffersize binding..