# WCF Call from Azure Webjob - The remote server returned an unexpected response: (413) Request Entity Too Large

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, azure-webjobs

I have gone through this post and answer in depth: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20667308/463196

and am still getting the `413 Request Entity Too Large Error` from the WCF Client (consumer of the Service Reference).

I've increased the maxXYZSize for everything, and my binding name "TransportSecurity" is bound to the endpoint correctly.

**From Web.config of Service (Provider)**:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="TransportSecurity" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" closeTimeout="10:00:00" openTimeout="10:00:00" receiveTimeout="10:00:00" sendTimeout="10:00:00">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="" name="GeneratePdf_CloudService.IService1">
      <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity" contract="GeneratePdf_CloudService.IService1" listenUri="">
        <identity>
          <dns value=""/>
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false before deployment -->
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Does anyone see anything I am missing?

Thanks!

**EDIT**: Oops.  Some more relevant information ... I am doing an Azure WebJob as the WCF Client, should have mentioned that.

So for all intents and purposes, it is a Client App that uses `AppName.exe.config`.  I am going to go and provide information on that end and see if it helps.

Comment: 413 is client error. What are you trying to send? Also enable includeExceptionDetailInFaults - that would give you more info.

Comment: @nikita A decent-sized Word Document, maybe 1 MB

Comment: Try to send hello world document. Would it be processed correctly?

Comment: @nikita Yes, small documents are fine.

Comment: Can you change http binding into tcp and send big document?