# Status code 413 (RequestEntityTooLarge) / Status code 415 (UnsupportedMediaType). WCF Programmatically

Tags: c#, wcf, svcutil.exe

I am calling a WCF web service programmatically by generating class files through [`SvcUtil.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/servicemodel-metadata-utility-tool-svcutil-exe).

All working fine but when I try to send an image (literally a file with size more than 200KB), I get this error.

I know I need to increase `maxReceivedMessageSize` and `maxBufferPoolSize` to the maximum to send large files to the WCF service. Hence, the XML version of doing this will be like below:

```
<binding name="SampleBinding" allowCookies="true" messageEncoding="Mtom" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" maxBufferSize="20000000" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
  <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxArrayLength="200000000" maxStringContentLength="200000000"/>
  <security mode="None">
    <transport proxyCredentialType="Basic"/>
  </security>
</binding>
```

In this app, since I am using class files generated by SvcUtil, I need to call my WCF service method programmatically.

So I did,

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = long.MaxValue;
binding.AllowCookies = true;
binding.ReaderQuotas = new System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas();
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = int.MaxValue;
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = int.MaxValue;
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = int.MaxValue;

webAPI = new WebAPIClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(soapUrl));
```

The XML version works really well but the C# version failed with below stack trace:

> There was an error on processing web request: Status code
>   413(RequestEntityTooLarge): Request Entity Too Large

**EDIT**

I have been approached to use custom binding. Below is my custom binding code:

```
CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding()
{
    Name = "SampleBinding",
    ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10, 0, 0),
    SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10, 0, 0),
};
var element1 = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement()
{
    ReaderQuotas = new System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas()
    {
        MaxDepth = 2147483647,
        MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647,
        MaxArrayLength = 2147483647,
        MaxBytesPerRead = 2147483647,
        MaxNameTableCharCount = 2147483647
    }
};
var element2 = new HttpTransportBindingElement()
{
    ManualAddressing = false,
    MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647,
    AllowCookies = false,
    AuthenticationScheme = System.Net.AuthenticationSchemes.None,
    BypassProxyOnLocal = false,
    MaxBufferSize = 2147483647,
    ProxyAuthenticationScheme = System.Net.AuthenticationSchemes.None,
    TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered,
    UseDefaultWebProxy = true
};
var element3 = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap12WSAddressing10, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

binding.Elements.Add(element1);
binding.Elements.Add(element2);
binding.Elements.Add(element3);

webAPI = new WebAPIClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(soapUrl));
```

> There was an error on processing web request: Status code
>   415(UnsupportedMediaType): Cannot process the message because the
>   content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not the
>   expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'.

I don't know what's wrong. May you help me?

Comment: Did you leave out the Mtom setting on your messageEncoding in the code variant on purpose or was that an oversight?

Comment: Nope, that was not on purpose. I mentioned generally

Comment: instead of MessageVersion.Soap12WSAddressing10 use MessageVersion.Soap11WSAddressing10 and in your custombinding use the Mtom binding: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.channels.mtommessageencodingbindingelement?view=netframework-4.8 also: did you set the  the requestLimits on your server: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits/

Comment: @rene, tried. no use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found an answer and posting the same here for future users who might have the same issue as me:

My client call

```
webAPI = new WebAPIClient(new BasicHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(_urlString);
```

Server Configuration for the WCF Service

```
<endpoint address="url/WebAPI.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MyContract.IWebAPI" />

<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

**As you can see I did not mention any name for the binding configuration here and it just worked like a charm.**

Answer inspired from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20667308/3682161)